# ViewBag In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

I am passing my model errors via the `ViewBag`. In my controller I am passing a `List<string>` that does contain values (`_modelErrors`) to the `ViewBag` and then I am trying to display this in my view.  When I debug in the view, my `ViewBag` does contain a `_modelErrors` dictionary with values, but my errors are not being rendered.

From my controller:

```
ViewBag._modelErrors = _modelErrors;
```

In my view I have tried all of these methods and yet no markup is rendered.

```
@try
{
    foreach (string er in ViewBag._modelErrors)
    {
        Response.Write(er.ToString());
        @Html.DisplayText(er) 
        @Html.DisplayText(er.ToString()) 
        @er.GetType()
        @er.ToString();
        er.ToString();
    }
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a dirty code, dude! Take a look at `@Html.ValidationSummary`  and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`

Well, some codes here to clarify stuff:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(ModelClass inputModel)
{       
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //for example we're trying to save our data to db
        var result = _myRepository.saveStuff(inputModel);

        if (result)
            return RedirectToAction("someAction");

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "An error occured, check input data");           
    }       
    return View(inputModel);
}
```

Also you can specify key (which is your model field name) instead of string.Empty -> so you'l see error message under specified field (as default), but basically what people do is exluding property errors from validation summary (`@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`) - so you get just general errors in that field. Hope it'l help

Comment: I know it is.  Most of my view is working fine using Html.ValidationMessageFor, but in this instance I need to use the ViewBag.

Comment: This is good advice; could you expand on your answer to help the OP solve his problem?  Maybe implement what you think he should do?

Comment: @BillGreer added code. You will see an error you've manually added to ModelState at `@Html.ValidationSummary` generated tag. Let me know if it's not clear for you

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
(string er in (List<string>)(ViewBag._modelErrors))
```

But was said this is bad practice. Also catching exceptions this way is so wrong...

Comment: "contain a _modelErrors dictionary with values". Perhaps you mean to cast this to an `IDictionary<String,String>`? (Unless I'm reading too far in to the wording, which, judging by the example the OP shows, I probably am ;p)

Comment: I don't now type of object he put in viewbag. In sample I don't see any mention of dictionary properties like key/values.